# Unable to save the file with .cpp format insted of .cpp.9.0 format in VCExpress

Tags: c++, visual-c++, codeblocks

I decided to try Visual C++ Express and didn't like it so I went back to Code::Blocks. However, when I tried to run a program in Code::Blocks I noticed that all of my files were saved under the format VCExpress.cpp.9.0. I deleted all of the files and went to where I have all of them uploaded to re-download them. However, they keep being saved as VCExpress.cpp.9.0. Can anyone offer assistance? Thanks.

P.S. They were uploaded before I ever tried VCExpress

If I try to compile one of these files I get an error saying "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive D:." In short, all cpp files are being saved as VCEXpress.cpp.9.0. I need to stop that file extension change from happening.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, try asking in the CB forums at http://forums.codeblocks.org/

Comment: Though having re-read your question, I don't think it has anything to do with Code::Blocks. Are you asking about file associations? These are Windows issues.

Comment: All .cpp files are being saved as VCExpress.cpp.9.0 files

Comment: Like, are the files being renamed or are they simply showing up as that under properties?

Comment: I was able to change it so that the files are being saved correctly (setting the default file format for code::blocks), but I still get the error message mingw32-g++.exe - No Disk : There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive D:.

Comment: Worked after a re-install of Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

See if re-installing Code::Blocks fixes the problem.